# PHP - Wordpress previous post link shows up on the last post

Tags: php, wordpress

Basically the code below shows the next category of posts instead of not showing.

```
<div class="post-previous"><?php previous_post_link('%link', true); ?></div>
```

I'd expect this to disappear if in the last loop of posts.

However the Next one does work how I expect it to it isn't shown if it is at the first of post:

```
<div class="post-next"><?php next_post_link('%link', true); ?></div>
```

This is a simple while loop with no crazyness:

```
<?php
    // Start the loop.
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        // Like so content in side
    endwhile;
?>
```

Anyone else had this problem?

Btw the next post isn't under the same category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably due to the fact that WordPress just sees posts and Custom Post types as the same thing unless you tell it otherwise. A quick look over at the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link) shows that there are attributes which you can use to limit the Prev/Next links to taxonomies etc.

Try this:

```
<?php next_post_link( $format, $link, $in_same_term = false, $excluded_terms = '', $taxonomy = 'category' ); ?>
```

Using the taxonomy option you can limit the links to only show 1 specific category, thus you shouldn't see a link on the last page of the specified category.

Comment: Sorry Jeremy better description of my issue

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to make `true` the third parameter like this:

```
<div class="post-previous"><?php previous_post_link('%link', null, true); ?></div>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link